# how to ignore a sensor being tripped the first time and start recording millis on the 2nd time it is tripped

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, millis

I am building a timing system that has a start, split and finish beams with this I am using a start gate that will drop when the race starts. when it drops it will trip the 1st sensor starting to count the millis which I am using to calculate the time. I am using IR sensors to that give me the 3 times based on the millis and then I do a calculation in excel that will give me the split and finish time.

Where I am running into issues is that after the person goes through the 3 timer sensors I have to close the start gate which trips the first sensor which messes up my times for the next person.

So I need to adjust my sketch so it takes this into consideration when it starts counting the millis. Basically I am thinking it needs a line of code to have the 1st sensor == LOW once and do nothing and then on the 2nd time that same sensor is == LOW it records the millis from that point.

Below is the sketch I am working on.

```
//timer
unsigned long start, reaction, push, elapsed; 


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(2, INPUT); // start switch
  pinMode(3, INPUT); // split sensor
  pinMode(4, INPUT); // finish sensor
}


void loop(){
   
if (digitalRead(2) == LOW)
  {

    start = millis();
    
  }



  if (digitalRead(3) == HIGH)
  {

    reaction = millis();
 //   delay(200); // for debounce   
    
    
  }

     if (digitalRead(4)==HIGH)
      {

       push=millis();
       delay(500); // for debounce

    Serial.print(start);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(reaction);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(push);
    Serial.println();

  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it really messes up the timing of the next person? When you reset the start gates, you code sets `start` to the current time. But then you you actually start the next race, you code overwrites `start` with the correct value. As long as you reset the gate **after** the last sensor is triggers (which actually prints out the times), you're fine, as far as I can see.

Comment: So what is happening is if when testing it out (just using my hand to break the beams) if I do it quickly it seems like I get a good result. but if I put the finish sensor far away from the split it gives me after calculations a number on the 1st time that is WAY too high when it should be the opposite.

Comment: So for example I get a start milli of 27083 split of 28657 finish of 29214. when I do the math to get m/s it turns out to be 1.574 from start to the split and .557 from the split to the finish...... I am not sure if this is a problem with my code or if it is a problem with my math?

Comment: Those millisecond values don't look odd to me, assuming the car is accelerating. I think you are calculating `s/m` not `m/s`. You should divide the distance (which I assume is 1m) by the number of seconds (which is 0.1574 and 0.557). Then you get an average of 0.64m/s in the first section. And an average of 1.8m/s in the second section.

Answer (score 1):

The start time will default to zero, so you could change it to:

```
if (digitalRead(2) == LOW && start == 0)
  {

    start = millis();
    
  }
```

Comment: You could also declare start as a static in the loop: ```static long start = millis();```. That way it gets called only the first time, and will remember the var in the rest of the loop()

Comment: with changing the sketch line to "if (digitalRead(2) == LOW && start == 0)" it seems that the first millis is always the same value as the first time it was tripped but the other sensors record what looks to be correct numbers.

Comment: *I am thinking it needs a line of code to have the 1st sensor == LOW once and do nothing* - that's what my suggestion does. If you want it to "reset" then you need more code. I'm not quite sure what your parameters are. How do you know you are starting a new race?